# Function's input appear to be a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a nested list and a header which is the column name.
I want to find maximum in column and print out the maximum's row information.
Here's my code.

```
def find_col(v):
    for i in range(1,31):
        if header[i]==v:
            return i

def col_list(col):
    list = []
    for row in linelist:    
        list.append(row[int(col)])
    return list

def M(col): 
    def max(li):                    
        inf = -float('inf')         
        maxnumber = inf
        for i, value in enumerate(li):
            if value>maxnumber:    
                maxnumber = value
        return maxnumber                    
    return max(col_list(col))
def max_row(col):
    li = col_list(col)
    m = M(col)
    for i, j in enumerate(li): 
        if j == m:
            return i

def col_max(name):
    col = find_col(name)
    return M(col)

def pri(name):
    column = find_col(name)
    maxima = M(column)
    li = col_list(column)
    maxrow = max_row(li)
    print(linelist[maxrow][1], linelist[maxrow][4], maxima)

pri('MP')
```

The problem is at function col_list, but I can't figure out how 'col' appear to be a list.

Comment: do you have a main method? or in what order are you calling these functions? I mean `col_list(col)` doesn't touch col until the `list.append` statement, so col in that function is whatever you call it with.

Comment: The col_list wok fine itself. However, when i run the pri function, it gave me error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seams to be that in the function `pri(name)` you call `max_row` in the statement `maxrow = max_row(li)` where `li` is what `col_list` returns (a list...) so you call `max_row(<somelist>)`. However, `max_row` then goes ahead and calls `col_list` with its input parameter (so a list, since it was passed a list...) that's where things go wrong.

How to fix it depends on what exactly you want to do. If I understand your intentions correctly something like:

```
li = []
for row in <imputParameter>: ## in your case its called col, but its a list...
  li.append(max(row)) ## or some other way to compute the value you want from that...
##continue function as in your case...
```

hope that helps.

Comment: @Z.Y.Jeng then you can accept the answer if you like. (tells people this question is answered...)